# Extracting 2 parts of a string using awk

Tags: awk, string

I would like to extract and print two patterns of a string

My file has hundreds of lines of text but here are two of them. Each line has a marker F1, F2, F4, F4, F5, F6, and F7 and each of these markers is followed by 4 characters.

```
F1A308F2A309 F3A310F4A311 F5A312F6A313F7A314

F1B308F2B309 F3B310F4B317 F5B312F6B313F7B315
```

I would like to extract the 4 characters after the pattern "F2" and the 4 characters after the pattern "F6" so that the output is

```
A309 A314

B309 B313
```

To clarify further I need to extract only the characters following F2 and F4.

Comment: Do you really want a pattern-based match - or just the last four characters of the first two whitespace-separated fields?

Comment: looks like column 2 is dropped (it has an "F4", not an F2 or F6)

Comment: note also that field 3 in both cases has two "F6"'s -- you want only the *last* F6?

Comment: @steeldriver it is pattern based. The F# markers could be anywhere on the string.

Comment: I have updated the text. I did not notice I had F6 twice on the second line

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following awk script is an approximation of what I think your requirement is:

```
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
    if (match($i, "F2....$") > 0) {
      printf "%s ", substr($i, RSTART + 2, 4);
    }
    if (match($i, "F6....$") > 0) {
      printf "% s", substr($i, RSTART + 2, 4);
    }
  }
  print ""
}
```

It loops through each line, then loops through each field of that line. For each element, if the tail end of the element has "F2" followed by 4 characters, then print those 4 characters followed by a space. Once it's done looping over a line, print a carriage return.

The output, based on your input, is:

```
A309 A314

B309 B315
```

---

An updated version of the awk script, to handle the elements existing anywhere within their field, only needs the `$` anchoring removed:

```
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
    if (match($i, "F2....") > 0) {
      printf "%s ", substr($i, RSTART + 2, 4);
    }
    if (match($i, "F6....") > 0) {
      printf "% s", substr($i, RSTART + 2, 4);
    }
  }
  print ""
}
```

Comment: Please note that the first version of this answer aligned with the first version of the question / input. It requires the F2/F6 text to be at the end of a field. The new version of the question/input has the text in the middle of a field, which would require at least the $ anchor to be removed.

Comment: Thanks - but let me bug you a little more. Where does the file name go? In my case the file name is test_awk2.txt on the same folder as the script #!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN  { print "test_awk2.txt" } {
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
    if (match($i, "F2....$") > 0) {
      printf "%s ", substr($i, RSTART + 2, 4);
    }
    if (match($i, "F6....$") > 0) {
      printf "% s", substr($i, RSTART + 2, 4);
    }
  }
  print ""
}

Comment: You'd call that awk script with a parameter or with redirected input: `./test_awk2.txt < input-file` or as `./test_awk2.txt input-file`.

Answer (score 2):

With Perl, using a lookbehind for the anchor characters:

```
$ perl -lne 'print join " ", /(?<=F2|F6)(.{4})/g' file
A309 A313

B309 B313
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
echo 'str' | egrep -o '(F2|F6)....' | egrep -o '....$' | xargs -n2
```